# Is it possible to run an active directory automation script on a specific rds terminal server or only on the domain controller?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, automation, active-directory, change-password

```
net user [Username] [Passwort]
```

When running this script on a slave RDS-Server, it won't work.
And when I change to the domain controller, where my active directory is located, it is possible to run the script.
Is it somehow possible to change the password for active directory users on any RDS-Server or is it only possible on the domain controller?

Maybe I could arrange it with the commandlet

```
    Invoke-Command
```

Or

```
New-PSSession
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Enter-PSSession <domain-controller>
net user <username> <password>
```